# Two factor authentication (MFA) in ASP.NET Core application with Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth, multi-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I have already created login flow with Identity Server 4 in my .NET Core application, but it is customized. I mean, flow is not following the classes like `UserManager` / `SignInManager` as Identity Server default implementation for user management, even tables for user are also customized in the database.

Please note, my project does not have `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser` as default identity.

Now I want to implement two factor authentication via Google Authenticator app in my application.

I have tried https://deblokt.com/2019/10/09/07-identityserver4-mfa-totp/ document, but did not have much success as login flow is not following legacy flow of Identity Server 4.

My questions are:

1. Can I still add Google Authenticator to achieve multi-factor authentication?
2. If yes, then how? Any suggestion or tutorial which I can refer to?
3. Please correct me if I misunderstood the concept

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Multi-factor authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-6.0).